# Triangle of numbers on Python

Tags: python, loops

I'm asked to write a loop system that prints the following:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
0 1 2
0 1
0
```

However, my script prints this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 


0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
# ... and so on
```

The code to be fixed is:

```
for row in range(10):
    for column in range(row):
        print ''
    for column in range(10-row):
        print column,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have too many loops, you only need two:

```
for row in range(10):
    for column in range(10-row):
        print column,
    print("")

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 
0 1 
0
```

Or importing print from future which will work for python2.7 and 3:

```
from __future__  import print_function

for row in range(10):
    for column in range(10-row):
        print(column,end=" ")
    print()
```

If you want  a one liner you can use join:

```
print("\n".join([" ".join(map(str,range(10-row))) for row in range(10)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one in python 3.x:

```
num = 9 
for a in range(num, -1, -1): 
    for b in range(0, a + 1):
        print(b, end=' ')
    print()
```